# addEventListener depending on setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, addeventlistener

How to call a function with addEventListener after setTimeout? Here is an example in code:

```
xyz = setTimeout(function () {
    [...blabla function...]
    // *(↓)
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load', blabla, false);
    } else {
        window.attachEvent('onload', blabla);
    }
}, 3000);
```

*(→): addEventListener calls the function when page loads, but he should call the "blabla" function only after the setTimeout of 3s. So, how to fix this?

Comment: You call a function with `addEventListener` by triggering the event you've added a listener for.  It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here.  Please state clearly what you expect to happen.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. The window's load event fires when the window is first loaded. Why do you need to add a handler for the event 3 seconds later? The event isn't going to fire again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to call a function 3 seconds after the window is loaded, you should put the `setTimeout` call *in* the handler:

```
function delayed_blah() {
    setTimeout(blabla, 3000);
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', delayed_blah, false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent('onload', delayed_blah);
```

For your application, what you want to do is call the `decrypt()` function from the animation callback:

```
$('#dlbox').animate({
    'top': '0'
}, 1000, decrypt);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/PxZwb/5/)

Comment: If you want something to happen after the overlay fades in, put it in the `fadeIn` callback function. What does the window load event have to do with this?

Comment: But you want the timeout to start after the fadeIn completes, right? So call `setTimeout` there.

Comment: no, he starts the timeout when you click 3s on the image. If you click 3s on the image, he will fadeIn the overlay with the purple "box". And when he fadeIn he should run the decrypting text effect.

Comment: Then do it in the code that starts the fadeIn after clicking 3s on the image.

Answer (score 2):

The "load" event would have already fired even before the event handler is attached because of the delay.

May be this will help.

```
function blahblah(){
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
      setTimeout(blahblah,3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to achieve whatever you are demanding. The code is given below.
In this, setTimeOut function is called when page has loaded completely.

```
 $(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            blabla();
        }, 3000);
    });
```